# How to mix the color of different colormap in Matlab

Tags: matlab, contour, colormap

I want the overlapping area to display the mixing color of the colormap(hot) and the colormap(cool).

For example,

```
contourf(peaks)
colormap(hot)
freezeColors
hold on
contourf(peaks')
colormap(cool)
```

Even I adjust the alpha value for tuning the transparency of the contour plot. The colors still do not look like a mixture of two different colormap. For example, one ring of contour 1 fill blue color, and another ring of contour 2 fill red color. In the overlapping area of ring of contour 1 and contour 2, I want to fill purple (red+blue) color on both contour 1 and contour 2, and non-overlapping area still keep original color (blue or red).

Does anyone have good ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please edit your question to explain *clearly* what you mean by a "mixture of two different colormap", it is not clear at all

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have added an example to explain what "the mixture of two different colormap" mean.

Comment: the [`freezeColors`](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943-freezecolors---unfreezecolors) is an external function from matlab central. It allows to use different colormap on a same `figure` but only on **different `axes`** (different subplot). I don't think there is a way to use 2 colormaps on the same axis. You have to create your own _mixed_ colormap, and offset the data so each of them will only be indexed on the part of the colormap where they belong.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The freezeColors can use different colormaps in the same axis. I have ever used 3 different colormap to plot three 2D contour in the same axis and figure. The problem I met is that I want to use a mixed colormap to emphasize the area of a partial overlapped contour. For other area else, it should keep original colormap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. The code is shown as blow.

im1=double(peaks(300));
im2=double(peaks(300)');
im1_rgb=summer(im1);
im2_rgb=cool(im2);
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(im1,2),1:size(im1,1));
data=im1_rgb/2+im2_rgb/2;
subplot(1,3,1)
tcolor(x,y,data)
hold on
[c,h1]=contour(x,y,im1);
set(h1,'LineColor','b')
[c,h2]=contour(x,y,im2);
set(h2,'LineColor','k')
hold off
subplot(1,3,2)
tcolor(x,y,im1_rgb)
hold on
[c,h1]=contour(x,y,im1);
set(h1,'LineColor','b')
hold off
subplot(1,3,3)
tcolor(x,y,im2_rgb)
hold on
[c,h2]=contour(x,y,im2);
set(h2,'LineColor','k')
hold off

Answer (score 0):

edit: I just read your edit, I don't this answer is what you wanted... I will just leave it here just in case.

the hold on command you are using is simply overwriting the previous points (besides the colormap is affects the global points so it wouldn't work anyway...). What you need to do is generate a new colormap which is the sum of your both old colormaps, and that goes a bit like this:

```
 Map1=colormap(hot);
 Map2=colormap(cool);
 CustomMap=Map1/2+Map2/2;
 imshow(ImageWhatever)
 colormap(CustomMap)
```

Hope that's wat you wanted!

Comment: Thanks for your response! If two contour is completely overlapped, it should work via using a mixed colormap. The problem I met is a partial overlapped contour plot. For overlapped area, I want it to show a mixed colormap. For other area else, it should keep original colormap.